# How can I list all the IP address and referrers of visitors of a specific node?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

The tracker module is active on the website and I want to get all the Track statistics of a node created.

`www.example.com/node/3/track` lists all the redirection etc. But what I want to do, is to get all IP addresses that visited this node:

In Track Tab I can see the logs but the IP address and the referrer details are not listed here, to see this info I have to visit the link (`www.example.com/admin/reports/access/24488` etc.) for per log listed in Track page.

**How can I list all the IP address and referrers of visitors of a specific node via Drupal interface, [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) or via PHPMyAdmin etc.?**

Comment: Hey herci, any feedback about my answer here?

Comment: Actually I did use the Visitors module. Although it has lots of features I can use it doesn't do what I exactly want. So, at that time I wrote a custom code to get this info directly from the DB. Thanks for your message.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) module. It comes with various reports, such as reports about pages that have recently been visited, or that have been hit frequently, or about pages count per month, day of month, day of week, hour. And it also includes a ***Referrers report*** (for referrer type either internal, external, or both).

One of the included reports is the [Recent hits](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/visitors/tree/reports/recent_hits.inc?h=7.x-2.x) report, a table with columns Date of visit, Title, Path and User ID of the visitor. If you follow any of the "details" links in that report, you'll get something that looks as in this example:

[image]

The demo site contains [some sample reports (charts)](http://drupal.placeto.be/visitors) available to anonymous users also.

You may also want to look at the [visitors_schema](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/visitors/tree/visitors.install?h=7.x-2.x#n37) to get an idea of the data that actually get logged (recorded) by this module.

In case the delivered reports are not a perfect fit, it's probably a very good starting point for some custom reporting. Either via a custom module that would simply have to query the data maintained by the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) module. Or via a straight forward custom report created with the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module.

Disclosure: I'm the maintainer of the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) module, 
and co-maintainer of the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module.